# How can I change the permalink of a translated home page?

Tags: url-rewriting, localization

I'm working on a site that has both an English and Spanish localization using the Polylang plugin. On every Spanish page besides the home page, I can change the permalink by clicking the "Edit" button next to the permalink:

[image: Permalink and edit button screenshot]

However, the home page does not have an option to edit the permalink:

[image: Home page permalink screenshot]

I'd like to change the home page permalink to `/es/inicio/`. Is this possible?

I tried updating the corresponding `post_name` in the `wp_posts` table but it just results in a 404 error when attempting to visit the home page.

Comment: in the wordpress settings, change the home page a few seconds just for editing this slug

Comment: @mmm great idea but it did not work

Comment: I found a solution that worked for me.
Please check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48607130